# intuition on the fundamental group of $S^1$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I am familiar with the proof that the fundamental group of the unit circle $S^1$ is $\mathbb Z$, yet I couldn't develop intuition for why it is true.
 For example, why would I fail if I try to find homotopy from a path that circles $S^1$ once to the path that stays at one point all the time? What brakes the continuity of such a homotopy?

Comment: It's the hole in the circle that's the problem. You'd have to break it to get past the hole (intuitively speaking).

Comment: The image of the homotopy must remain in $S^1$.

Comment: If m and n are distinct integers, what would make a loop going around the circle n times different from one going around the circle m times? Can we not deform one into the other?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- Find a tree and a rope.
- Fix the rope to the ground.
- Walk around the tree with the rope.
- Connect the two ends of the rope.
- Try to pull all the rope close to you.

Does it work? No, you are stuck with a rope that goes around the tree once.

Comment: If aliens capture you and transport you to a different planet, there is a similar way to determine the homotopy type of the planet : find a very long rope and a dog, tie the dog's collar with the rope, and let the dog roam around the planet...

Comment: This answer requires unbounded trees and infinitely strong rope.

Comment: But this proof presupposes the existence of such a dog on the planet.

Comment: If m and n are distinct integers, what would make a loop going around the circle n times different from one going around the circle m times? Can we not deform one into the other?

Comment: @ensbana sorry for the late reply. But you can try this with some rope and a tree. Walk around the tree several times, then you have the rope passing around the tree several times and you cannot alter this. If you do it twenty times the tree is  covered in rope and you cannot transform this in a clean situation where you just walked around once. If you don't have a tree and rope handy a shoelace and a pencil will do. (But don't move the lace over the top of the pencil. You'd need to treat the pencil as infinitely long.)

Answer (score 3):

For me the mathematical, and also intuitive,  reason involves the relation of groupoids to groups.

[image: circle]

Here the groupoid $\mathsf I$ has two objects $0,1$ and only one non trivial arrow $\iota: 0 \to 1$. But when you identify $0,1$ you can iterate the image of $\iota$.

The appropriate groupoid theory, leaned from [Philip Higgins](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/7/tr7abs.html),  is developed in the 1968, 1988 and 2006 editions  of the book now titled [Topology and Groupoids](http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html), but that book is to my knowledge the **only** topology text in English to explain to students this more powerful result.

The concept  of "**the** fundamental group of a space" is a bit of a misconception, the precise notion being that of "**the** fundamental group of a space with base point". In 1967, I introduced the notion of the fundamental groupoid $\pi_1(X,C)$ of a space $X$ with a set $C$ of base points, in order to obtain a version of the Seifert-van Kampen Theorem which could compute the fundamental group of the circle, and much more. See the discussion at this [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40945/compelling-evidence-that-two-basepoints-are-better-than-one) question. Choosing just one base point seems  to imply that all spaces are assumed path connected.

Grothendieck wrote to me in 1983: "To make an analogy, it would be just impossible to work at ease with algebraic varieties, say, if sticking from the outset (as had been customary for a long time) to varieties which are supposed to be connected. Fixing one point, in this respect (which wouldn't have occurred in the context of algebraic geometry) looks still worse, as far as limiting elbow-freedom goes! Also, expressing a pointed $0$-connected homotopy type in terms of a group object mimicking the loop space (which isn't a group object strictly speaking), or conversely, interpreting the group object in terms of a pointed "classifying space", is a very inspiring magic indeed - what makes it so inspiring is that it relates objects which are definitively of a very different nature - let's say, "spaces" and "spaces with group law". The magic shouldn't make us forget though in the end that the objects thus related are of different nature, and **cannot be confused without causing serious trouble**." [My emphasis]

To add another point, the pushout of groupoids above is a special case of a pushout of the form 
$$\begin{matrix}C & \xrightarrow{f} & D\\
\downarrow && \downarrow  \\
G & \to & f_*(G)\end{matrix}$$
where $C=Ob(G)$ and $f:C \to D$ is a function, with both $C$ and $D$ regarded also as discrete groupoids, so that $C \to G$ is the inclusion. In the case $G=\pi_1(X,C)$ for a space $X$, and with conditions on $C$, $f_*(G)$ is isomorphic  to $\pi_1(Y,D)$ where $Y= D \cup_f X$. Thus the use of $\pi_1(X,C)$ allows us to consider identifications among a set of base points, something not conceivable if you have only one base point. The construction of $f_*(G)$ includes the construction of free groups, free products of groups, free groupoids, ..., one construction using words instead of several, see the books [Higgins](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/7/tr7abs.html), [T&G](http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html), but with a different notation.